# python: replace item in a list with items in a another list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'name': ['sarah', 'emily', 'brett'], 'location': ['LA', 'NY', 'Texas']}
```

I also have a list:

```
l = ['name', 'location']
```

I want to replace 'name' in the list `l` with the list `['sarah', 'emily', 'brett']` in dictionary `d` (same thing for location).

So the outcome would be:

```
l = ['sarah', 'emily', 'brett', 'LA', 'NY', 'Texas']

for item in l:
    l.append(d[item])
    l.remove(item)
```

this is what I did and I got a type error, unhashable type: 'list'.
what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the list inside the loop if you are iterating in the items of that list.

Try creating a new one and then rename it. The garbage collector will take care of old version of `l`.

```
new_l = [] 
for item in l:
    new_l.extend(d[item])
l = new_l
```

Comment: Tip: use `new_l.extend()` to get OP's expect output.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to create a new list:

```
l = [y for x in l for y in d[x]]
```

The results are the flattened substituted items:

```
print l
>>> ['sarah', 'emily', 'brett', 'LA', 'NY', 'Texas']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
l = [d.get(k, k) for k in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't change list when you are looping in, because iterator will not be informed of your changes.

To replace them, just generate a new one containing `d` lists selected with `l` items.

```
[d[item] for item in l]
```

If you are not sure that all items in `l` are keys in `d` you can add test before trying to get from `d`:

```
[d[item] for item in l if d.has_key(item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

replace .append() with .extend()

```
tmp = []
for i in l:
    tmp.extend(d[i])
l = tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the item in list only partial shown in dictionary. To avoid error I used:

`[y for x in l for y in d.get(x,[x])]`

When test data changed like:

```
l = ['name', 'location', 'test']
```

The result would like below:

```
print([y for x in l for y in d.get(x,[x])])
>>> ['sarah', 'emily', 'brett', 'LA', 'NY', 'Texas', 'test']
```